# Mapping of line spacing in XD and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, adobe, adobe-xd

We received design from another team who created the XD file.
In that XD file, we found some controls having line spacing = 44

[image]

Now, Line spacing property mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1528742-linespacing):

**Now Question is, How to map XD's line spacing with Swift's Line spacing ?**
[image]

Comment: How about 1:1? `lineSpacing = 44`!?

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for reply, tried that but with 44 in swift it adds huge gap between lines.

Answer (score 0):

lineSpacing = lineHeight - fontSize

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community: +1 (as a swift coder...) it seems pretty clear to me. [I know its a bot, but I'm now curious how #chatty the bot can be]